# Курсор в конец строки

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть `edit control`, на который я навожу фокус через `setFocus`, но при этом курсор оказывается в начале строки. Как его перенести в конец?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775460(v=vs.85).aspx

1. [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) для отправки сообщений.
2. [`GetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) или [`WM_GETTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627(v=vs.85).aspx) чтобы получить длину текста.
   Пока не могу найти подтверждение, вернут ли они длину, если передать null и 0.
3. [`EM_SETSEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761661(v=vs.85).aspx) чтобы поставить курсор в нужную позицию.